# InputStreamReader throws IOException

Tags: java, io

I'm trying to use an InputStreamReader to read bytes sent by a socket
I have

```
InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
in.read();
```

This throws an IOException :(. I know the socket should be sending something but it keeps throwing the error.

Comment: Can you provide the error message and stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

The actual error message and stack trace would indeed be useful.

You could try using a BufferedReader and using readLine to make sure you are getting something.[enter link description here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class EchoClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Socket echoSocket = null;
        PrintWriter out = null;
        BufferedReader in = null;

        try {
            echoSocket = new Socket("taranis", 7);
            out = new PrintWriter(echoSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                        echoSocket.getInputStream()));
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Don't know about host: taranis.");
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for "
                               + "the connection to: taranis.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

    BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(
                                   new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String userInput;

    while ((userInput = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {
        out.println(userInput);
        System.out.println("echo: " + in.readLine());
    }

    out.close();
    in.close();
    stdIn.close();
    echoSocket.close();
    }
}
```

Found [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html)

Answer (score 0):

That is expected behaviour, IOException is signalling that there is nothing to read, most probably socket has not connected properly.  This question should be closed.